# Hash table where key is string and value is function in c++

Tags: c++, hash

Is it possible to have an implementation for hash, where key is `String` and value is `function`. For the background, I have a program where there is lots of string comparison, i.e.

```
if(strcasecmp(s,"london")==0) 
   functionA();  
else if(strcasecmp(s,"moscow")==0)
   functionB();  
else if(strcasecmp(s,"delhi")==0)  
   functionC();  
  ...
```

and so on.

But this kind of implementation is very costly `(theta(n))`, since `String` comparison is done for all the if statements. If we have an hash implementation where key is `String` and value is `function`, we can just call something like

```
function = hash.Get("moscow");    
function();
```

Its complexity is good `(theta(log(1)))`.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: `std::map` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Or `std::unordered_map`, if complexity should be `O(1)` and hashing `O(m)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to have an implementation for hash, where key is String
>   and value is function?

Yes. This is perfectly feasible. You can use pointers to function or `std::function`. Possible containers might be:

1. std::unordered_map
2. boost::unordered_map